# Vim remap “Inside” and “Around”

Tags: vim, neovim

I use colemak as my keyboard layout and have mapped insert to `s` and append to `v`, and have a similar situation with my `a` key. Using anything like `dsc` instead of the common `dic` or `cap` For example does not work with the setup. How can i also remap the ‘inside’ and ‘around’ features of `a` and `i` for when they are ready to be used?

Comment: what you mean omap? (`:h omap-info`)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [operator pending mappings](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html)

Try the following in nvim

```
:onoremap s i
:onoremap v a
```